# Audio input not working; greyed out in pavucontrol [Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS]

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio

Audio input used to work fine.

I tried restarting pulseaudio with `killall pulseaudio` and `pulseaudio -k`, followed by `pulseaudio --start`

pavucontrol screenshots:

[image: input greyed out]

[image: config looks fine]

Also I looked up how to list audio input devices and tried that, in case it's helpful:

```
$ aplay --list-devices
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

That's my built-in mic right? I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Can yo utry to look trough ALL the input/outputs in pavucontrol? (in the Configuration tab)  (In my case when I had the same problem, I had very many many to choose from (a drop down) So I just tried 1 by another and eventually, 1 of them worked: But This may or may not be the case here, although posted this in case this would be the problem. Hope it solves itself!

Comment: @WilliamMartens I didn't have a lot of options, and none of them changed anything :(

Comment: Oh im sorry to ehar that;  Edited my comment below

Comment: I updated my answer, I had the exact same problem today, I don't know if it will work for you; but If you try it,  and it dosen't work:  Tell me what the output is and I will try to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your Built-In Analog Stereo, you have it on mute (Is it not?) Click on it (the, muted speaker button) to Un-Mute it, does that help?

EDIT:
I had this problem exactly today,  a quick copy & paste from my own post:

[No sound 18.04 and tried all the answers I can find](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277911/no-sound-18-04-and-tried-all-the-answers-i-can-find/1277939#1277939)

I **(In my case)** solved it by

```
removing pavucontrol
rebooting
Install pavucontrol again,
and it started working!
```

To do this in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt remove pavucontrol
sudo apt autoremove
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Hope this solves itself!

Good luck!

Comment: Where are you seeing a muted speaker button?

Comment: @mavix At the Input devices tab , monitor of built-in audio digital stereo (hdmi)   ,  not 2nd:  Monitor of Built-in audio analog stereo,  (But here, 3rd: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo (Internal Microphone) at this line, look to the right, 3 buttons: a greyd out (muted) speaker,  and a lock,  and a  green,  Ok-symbol)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuX3l.png At this

Comment: well.. this is embarrassing...

Comment: @mavix Hey! Did it work?  So I don't misunderstand;   It's nothing embarrassing at all! the Icon is so small, so easy to miss,  hehe ^^  Hope it worked; Glad if.   //Regards! Have a great day sir!

Comment: Yes, it was indeed the problem. I missed the icon hahaha thanks so much @William Martens

Comment: @mavix Writing this comment just to say  thank you to you too; Good luck with everything you do!  //Wishes

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Sound -> Input.
Check the status of your microphone.
It may have the volume at zero.