# Microphone not working in all browsers in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound

I've recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. Now, I saw that none of the browsers could get audio from microphone. It just gets noise. But when I use Zoom app, the audio is fine. I need to use Google Meet and I can't talk using my mic. Please help.

Comment: Hi,  does this answer your question  ?
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1277911/no-sound-18-04-and-tried-all-the-answers-i-can-find/1277939#1277939

Comment: @WilliamMartens Sorry, but that doesn't work. I even installed windows and every single browser could get nothing but noise from the builtin microphone of my laptop. But other apps like sound recorder could get the audio.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry to hear that;  Hope someone just comes along which is professional at this  with audio problems and can solve it :/

Comment: @heynnema Can you help me?